# Enable start listening feature of Bing speech in webchat automatically

Tags: botframework, chatbot, speech, web-chat, bing-speech

I have already integrated the Bing speech API using speech recognizer. It is working as expected. Now we had an additional requirement to enable the speech listening capability once an event/action is completed in the web chat.

**How can we enable the speech listening automatically?**

How yo make the Chatbot (Web chat) always listening once you click the microphone icon? Customer need continuous voice conversation without mouse click. The voice conversation can be stopped with the next mouse click on microphone.

Comment: `How yo make the Chatbot (Web chat) always listening once you click the microphone icon?` It seems that you’d like to make microphone always on after you click the microphone button, as far as I know, currently it does not enable us to do this. [This github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/859) discussed similar question, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

The [new speech service SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/) allows you to use StartContinousRecognitionAsync() to listen to microphone input and get recognition result via events, until you call StopContinuousRecognitionAsync(). Please see the sample ContinuousRecognitionAsync() [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/Windows/csharp_samples/speech_recognition_samples.cs#L143) for how to use both methods.